# [@.disabled]="true" causes console errors

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I want to disable the angular animation at certain times and therefor found the 
 `[@.disabled]="isDisabled"` in the [docs](https://angular.io/api/animations/trigger#disabling-animations).

So I wanted to use it in like this: `[@.disabled]="true"` (just to test it) and I get constant errors:
[image]

**Error Text:**

```
ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '[@.s' is not a valid attribute name.
    at DefaultDomRenderer2.push.../../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js.DefaultDomRenderer2.setAttribute (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:134848:16)
    at AnimationRenderer.push.../../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/animations.js.BaseAnimationRenderer.setAttribute (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:133467:23)
    at DebugRenderer2.push.../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DebugRenderer2.setAttribute (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:85125:23)
    at createElement (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:81803:22)
    at createViewNodes (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:84036:26)
    at createEmbeddedView (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:83983:5)
    at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:84997:25)
    at Object.debugCreateEmbeddedView [as createEmbeddedView] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:84521:12)
    at TemplateRef_.push.../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.TemplateRef_.createEmbeddedView (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:82564:38)
    at ViewContainerRef_.push.../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ViewContainerRef_.createEmbeddedView (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:82430:35)
```

**Code:**

```
  <ng-container *ngIf="!something" [@.disabled]="true">
    ....
    <div [@fadingListAnimation]="otherthing">
```

Is there an import missing? Why is it saying '`'[@.s' is not a valid attribute name.` the attribute is `@.disabled`?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to place the disabled animation on the same element with the animation?

Comment: And ng containers aren't rendered, how are you supposed to animate them anyway !

Comment: @Christian from the doku:  Place the @.disabled binding on an element to disable animations on the element itself, as well as any inner animation triggers within the element.

Comment: @trichetriche: yes that did the trick :). placing it on the same element, works too now (could have sworn it didn't). If you post it as an answer I will accept it :)

Comment: @Stefan not mine, notify Christian ! (But if I were you, I would delete my question, as it's only a typo on your end, hence making it non reproductible)

Comment: @trichetriche no the problem was that the animation was on the 'ng-container'. So not a typo, and it is a information which is not in the documentation. So it's a pretty niche problem but maybe it helps somebody.....

Comment: Oh okay then !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove your disabled animation from the `ng-container`, as those containers aren't rendered on the final HTML page.

You can't animate what doesn't exist !